# How to remove overflow on printing CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the overflow-y: scroll; property I need to remove this property when user execute the print (Ctrl+P)

```
<div id="taskList" class="uk-padding-small">

</div>

<style>

 #taskList{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            min-height: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }

@media print {
#taskList{
        overflow-y: auto;
        min-height: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}
</style>
```

This work fine with other properties like width, margin, padding. But I can't overwrite the overflow-y property  and my document don't show the full content.
[image: screen]

You can try this runnable. 
https://jsfiddle.net/atsuya007/j3f6d8ht/

Comment: What's wrong with just using `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: so the page is printed with the scroll? you are able to scroll printed page?

Comment: @AmrNoman overflow:hidden doesnt't work my div is taking everytime height:400px;

Comment: @TemaniAfif no, the scroll is part of the document; it is only one page

Comment: share the full code, the issue may be somewhere else

Comment: @TemaniAfif you can try this runnable issue: https://jsfiddle.net/atsuya007/j3f6d8ht/

Comment: be sure to make the media print at the end of the CSS, it's not the case in your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif that is not the problem, at end or start overflow isn't working

Comment: your fiddle is working fine for me when added at the end

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, I forgotten click run, it is working, thank you (:

Comment: @TemaniAfif how I can make your comment as right answer?

Comment: well you cannot :) but since you got what you need don't bother your self with this ;)

Comment: Also, hide the print button when printing. It will print perfect print as you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure to make the media print at the end of the CSS.

Comment: Currently the top hit on google. I'm surprised this doesn't have more views.

Comment: @Chad 2022 i have the same problem , i had encountered my own question hahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

By reversing the logic, it works

```
.fullheight{
  min-height:100%;
  height:fit-content;
}   
@media screen {
    .fullheight{
      height:100%;
      overflow:auto
    }
}
```